# CSV not properly being parsed on new lines

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, csv, file-get-contents

I have a CSV file that looks like:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3
value1,value2,value3
value11,value12,value13
value21,value22,value23
```

etc...

When I use this code to parse through it:

```
$csvData = file_get_contents($file_url);
$lines = explode(" ", $csvData);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
dpm($array);
```

the first value of a line always ends up being part of the end of the last header:
[image]

EDIT: There must have been an issue with cache as this is working fine.

Comment: Why are you exploding on space?

Comment: @Alma - str_getcsv() is a standard PHP function

Comment: Why not use `fgetcsv()` directly? That `explode()` is likely mangling your input if any of the lines/fields contain spaces naturally.

Comment: @AlmaDo str_getcsv is a function built into PHP and dpm is Drupal function that just prints out similar to var_dump. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: The `dpm()` function is from the OP's [**other question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19815824/1415724) – @Alma – Which may even play a role here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- dpm() is just a Drupal function that prints whatever data you want into the messages area of a Drupal site.  It has not affect on either question's code.

Comment: I learned something new then, thanks @CR47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reading CSV file explode() and file_get_contents() are not the correct options. Go for [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)
You can do like below for reading CSV file:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to break lines into newlines (`"\n"`) instead of just spaces (`" "`). Even better, you might want to use [`file()`](http://www.php.net/file) to load file lines into an array. Better yet, you might want to use [`SplFileObject`](http://www.php.net/splfileobject) class to do that:

```
<?php
$file = new SplFileObject($file_url);
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY
    | SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE | SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);
$data = array();

foreach ($file as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use `file` instead of `file_get_contents`. That will return an array with one line of the input file on each index. This will work with all possible new line characters.

```
$lines = file($file_url, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)
```